# Can we say calling any normal method is also called Abstraction as it provides its functionality and hide implementation?

Tags: oop, abstraction

```
class A
{
   void method1()
  {
     System.out.println("Hi Everybody...!");
  }
}

Class B
{
 public static void main(String args[]){
 A a =new A();
 a.method1(); 
}
}
```

In this case, can we say a.method1(); is Abstraction where it does providing only functionality 
 rather than how it implemented?

It might be silly :-) but i got confused as it does the same.
I have read in internet and everywhere it says just car/phone/etc gives functionality rather than implementation(how it designed) details. Can we achieve abstraction without interface and abstraction class ?